# TypeError: options.series is undefined in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

Why can't i able to modify series by `options.series` way?
I need to set color for nth series, i have multiple charts running through loops.

So i need to set 1st chart's 5th series color. Is it possible to set color in the below way?

```
 var options = {
                   series:
                      nth : { color : 'green'}
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this

```
var options = {
                   series:
                      nth : { color : 'green'}
                   }
```

Since it's not a valid Object

**UPDATE:**

By seeing [google-visualisation API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart). The `keys` for `series` object are digits. so we can access them by `options.series["n"]` n = 5.

Since keys are numbers, we can't use `object.number` or `series.5`

An example

```js
var options = {
  series: {5: {color: 'green'}}
};
    
console.log(options.series["5"]);
```

Comment: It won't work like that, I tried this earlier that's why this question. try this code with google chart and u will know about it.

Comment: @AravindhGopi, Let me look at that API, what chart you are trying to do this?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Google ComboChart. but i need to know how to access `series` object by JS in any kinda google chart.

Comment: Yes @AravindhGopi, Updated answer

Comment: Thanks, but its working with numbers, not with the variables.